# do both json.load() and json.dump() at once in Python

Tags: python, json, file, file-handling

I am trying to do something like this which uses reading , appending and writing at the same time.

```
with open("data.json", mode="a+") as file:
            # 1.Reading old data
            data = json.load(file)  
            # 2. Updating old data with new data
            data.update(new_dict)
            # 3.Writing into json file
            json.dump(data,file,indent=4)
```

But it shows `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: You are appending a JSON string at the end of another, making the on-disk file invalid. You should read from the file in `r` mode, then re-open it in `w` mode to overwrite it.

Comment: I assume the error is at the time of `json.load`. Check the content of `data.json`. You seem to be appending JSON to the file, instead of replacing it, resulting in two JSON being in the file one after another after the code runs once, which would mess up the second invocation. Use `file.seek(0)` to return to the start before writing.

Comment: Yes I want to append in
 {
    "google": {
        "email": "sujalgupta@gmail.com",
        "password": "8QU7w51VE$!dbCU"
    }
}

with file.seek(0) it is giving same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717534/pythonic-way-to-update-multiple-values-stored-within-a-json-dict/67717833#67717833

Answer (score 0):

First you need to open the file in `mode="r+"`. Update the old data with new, then `seek(0)` to the beginning of the file, write your updated json data, and then truncate the rest:

```
with open("data.json", mode="r+") as file:
    file.seek(0, 2)
    if file.tell():
        file.seek(0)
        data = json.load(file)  
        data.update(new_dict)
    else:
        data = new_dict
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
    file.truncate()
```

Reason it doesn't work with `a+` mode is that it will always write at the end of the file, irrespective of `seek(0)`. So your updated json data just gets appended to the older one  like a normal text data, but since its not a valid json syntax, it causes **JSON Decode** error.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function/1466036) for more detailed info on how the different open modes work.

Comment: This doesn't work .
Check Line 55
https://replit.com/@heysujal/Password-manager#main.py

Comment: @Sujal Ok I checked your code and `data.json` file. The issue is that initially your `data.json` is an empty file. So `json` cannot load it since it needs a valid entry. I have modified the code to handle this. Try the edited code now above.

Comment: I will let you know when I try this.